# From one VC to another VC but after that everything hang

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hi I manage to go from `TopVC` to the `BottomVC` by using the following code. But after that my `bottomVC` will not work. `BottomVC` will not go forward when link is clicked.

[image: FromTopToBottom]

## Edited Answer

## Top VC I use the following code to go to bottomVC, Did I actually go to BottomVC or BottomClass?

```
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BuyCredit"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    UINavigationController* classesNav = (UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.viewControllers[4];
    BuyCredit *classesViewController = [classesNav.viewControllers firstObject];
    [classesViewController fromClassBook:sURL];
```

## Bottom VC Suppose to load another VC when a link is clicked, but everything just hang

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    sURL = self.urlString;

    NSLog(@"Receiving From and the sURL :  %@", sURL);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

}

- (void)fromClassBook:(NSString*)string {

    sURL = string;
    NSLog(@"Please pass over **** %@", sURL);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    PurchaseDet *target = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PurchaseDet"]) {

        target.urlString = sURL;

    } 
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *URL = [request URL];
    NSString *theString = [URL absoluteString];
    NSRange match;

    NSLog(@"Detect the URL theString :  %@", theString);

    match = [theString rangeOfString: @"PHPSMI"];

    //--- If the URL string does not contain purchase_det.asp meaning it will load the webview
    if (match.location == NSNotFound) {
        sURL = theString;
        return YES; //--- Load webview

    } else {  //--- Because currently the purchase confirm page is just another page, hence will reload the current webview.

        NSLog(@"Will pass to SEQUE and called the URL :%@",theString);
        //--- Calling this method will tell the segue hey I want to redirect to another viewController.
        //--- Update the sURL with the latest String
        sURL = theString;

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PurchaseDet" sender:self];

        return NO; // Don't load the webview, capture the sURL and trigger NewsDet segue, and then pass sURL as urlstring to destination VC
    }

}
@end
```

Comment: here you set wrong values

Comment: Top VC I use the following code to go to bottomVC, Did I actually go to BottomVC or BottomClass? -- this code take to you BottomVC

Comment: hey buddy try now.

Comment: RB1509 i think it is not my segue, if i navigate to my bottomVC normally it will present properly. i think it is the way I present to my bottomVC. I am now trying  @ketaki Damale suggestions but thanks a lot, I deeply appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];`

With

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

**Note:-** 
You are only presenting bottomVC on TopVC.Hence the rootViewController remains TopVC.Therefore when you call `performSegueWithIdentifier` It gets nil object for bottomVC.

Try this..

Comment: Still not going to the `bottomVC` I got the following error `2018-04-20 19:37:18.541302+0800 SFITNESS[62196:5508216] -[More fromClassBook:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc289713270
2018-04-20 19:37:18.541549+0800 SFITNESS[62196:5508216] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[More fromClassBook:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc289713270`

Comment: Is it because it is embedded in a TabBarController then a NavigationController then the next VC?